# How to change background image position and rotation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, background-image, flutter-layout, image-rotation

I'm new in Flutter and I want to know how can I change position of background image in Flutter. I want to show background image in a corner of page and change it's position to hidden parts of image because of ovelflow.

As a frontend developer to achieve this, I think about changing position of image to absolute and set bottom and right to minus values but doing these in Flutter is in a different way.

How can I achieve this in Flutter?

```
class _WaterIntakeState extends State<WaterIntake> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5), BlendMode.dstATop),
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/drink-water.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            )),
          ),
          Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Water Intake'),
            ),
            body: Container(
//              child: const ButtonsWidget(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Current Status :

[image]

What I want :

[image]

Comment: Did the answer posted below worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use both the `Transform.translate` and `Transform.rotate` to achieve this.

```
class _WaterIntakeState extends State<WaterIntake>
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(-100.0, 200.0),
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: pi / 4,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                      Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5), BlendMode.dstATop),
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/drink-water.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Water Intake'),
            ),
            body: Container(
//              child: const ButtonsWidget(),
                ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Ofc you need to play with the `offset`.

Answer (score 8):

Just replace your second container with this **Transform.translate** widget

```
Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(-100.0, 200.0),
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: pi / 4,
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                      Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5), BlendMode.dstATop),
                  image: AssetImage("assets/images/drink-water.png"),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Also you can change the image position according to you by updating angle and offset